# Handling variable DECIMAL data in SQL

Tags: sql, decimal

I have schedule job to pull data from our legacy system every month. The data can sometime swell and shrink. This cause havoc for `DECIMAL` precision.

I just found this job failed because `DECIMAL(5,3)` was too restrictive. I changed it to `DECIMAL(6,3)` and life is back on track.

Is there any way to evaluate this shifting data so it doesn't break on the `DECIMAL()`?

Thanks,

-Allen

Comment: Fix the data type.  Declare it as something like 'decimal(10, 3)`.  Then you won't have to worry about it breaking.

Comment: @Gordon until a data point of `12345678.321` is encountered :)

Comment: Some platforms have a vardecimal datatype. Which is yours?

Comment: Please add the tag for your DBMS. `postgresql`, `oracle`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to evaluate this shifting data so it doesn't break on the DECIMAL()

Find the maximum value your data can have and set the column size appropriately.

Decimal columns have two size factors:  scale and precision.  Set your precision to as many deimal paces you need (3 in your case), and set the scale based on the largest possible number you can have.

A `DECIMAL(5,3)` has three digits of precision past the decimal and 5 total digits, so it can store numbers up to `99.999`.  If your data can be 100 or larger, use a bigger scale.

If your data is scientific in nature (e.g. temperature readings) and you don't care about *exact* equality, only showing trends, relative value, etc.) then you might use `real` instead.  It takes less space than a `DECIMAL(5,3)` (4 bytes vs 5), has 7 digits of precision (vs. 5) and a range of `-3.4E38` to `3.4E38` (vs `-99.999` to `99.999`).

`DECIMAL` is more suited for financial data or other data where exact equality is important (i.e. rounding errors are bad)